Why does my paste of `image/jpeg` data not work on some X11 applications (mainly Chrome)?
I am running X11 11.0 / X.Org 1.21.1.7 on Debian 12, though I have the feeling this is not related to my particular version of X11.
I have a script that does an image capture from my screen using import from ImageMagick 6.9.11-60; the exact command is import png:- or import jpeg:-. In both cases, if I redirect the output to a file, file appears to indicate that it's in the correct format and it's viewable with the ImageMagick display command. The file output for a JPEG I just captured is
JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01, aspect ratio, density 1x1, segment length 16, baseline, precision 8, 88x56, components 

My script doesn't write the output to a file; instead it places it in the X11 clipboard buffer, with $format set to jpeg or png:
import "$@" "$format:-" | xclip -sel clip -t "image/$format" -i

When I capture a PNG image, I can then paste it without problems into any program I've tried. But when I capture a JPEG image, it doesn't work in, as far as I can tell, Chrome and Electron-based programs. It does work when pasting into the Telegram desktop client, which I think is not Electron-based.
What might be going wrong here, and how might I fix (or at least debug) it?
